# Doubts about gcc O3 optimisation flag

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

I have g++ 4.7.3 compiler. I'm trying to follow the optimisation flags description http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/Optimize-Options.html and have a next problem:

I have a program, which gives different times with -O2 and -O3 flag. -O2 is twice faster than -O3. Time is 8ms with O2 and 16ms with O3.

So I would like to understand what exactly makes difference. In the link above I see:

"O3 Optimize yet more. -O3 turns on all optimizations specified by -O2 and also turns on the -finline-functions, -funswitch-loops, -fpredictive-commoning, -fgcse-after-reload, -ftree-vectorize and -fipa-cp-clone options."

So I simply take -O2 and add all described flags:

```
-O2 -finline-functions -funswitch-loops -fpredictive-commoning -fgcse-after-reload -ftree-vectorize -fipa-cp-clone
```

And time is 30ms. **But this set of options should be *equivalent* to -O3. Why time is different?** Where do I do something wrong?

P.S. All results are perfectly reproducible with precision of 1ms.

---

I have checked the options using

```
g++ -c -Q -Ox --help=optimizers
```

and saw that O3 has one more additional option: -ftree-loop-distribute-patterns. But when I add it the the options set:

```
-O2 -finline-functions -funswitch-loops -fpredictive-commoning -fgcse-after-reload -ftree-vectorize -fipa-cp-clone -ftree-loop-distribute-patterns
```

the speed is still 30ms.

Comment: Optimization is not a perfect science. There's no definite reason to think you're doing anything wrong (but since you haven't provided your methodology for taking these measurements, there's no way to know that you're not doing something wrong as well).

Comment: At least GCC optimization options don't guarantee faster performance for performance options set. There are many things, less size could speed up performance more, e.g. cache hits, branch prediction, etc.

Comment: For what it's worth, the docs do **not** explicitly say that -O3 is -O2 plus some extra options - they may do entirely different things _in addition to_ turning on those optimization flags, at least by the documentation wording you have posted.

Comment: Without seeing what your code does, it's hard to even speculate as to why your code is slower in -O3 than in -O2. But it's not impossible that bigger code runs slower, either because of worse code-cache hit ratio, or because of "compiler didn't do it's job properly" - or because of some bug in the compiler that causes bad code to be generated when some particular condition is encountered.

Comment: @Mats Perersson, my question is not about code at all, it is about optimisation flags. I am not asking why it is slower, I am asking why time CAN BE different?

Comment: Ok, so the answer to that is in my comment: Different compiler options produce different code. Sometimes a "better" optimisation turns out to be worse.

Comment: And why the options are different? They should be exactly same. This is my point.

Comment: @klm123: One reason is that `-O3` sometimes results it larger code that will not fit in the cache(s) where the `-O2` code would fit.  It matters.  A lot.

Comment: The main reason is probably that `-O3` does things that are not covered by specific options. Thus, it is probably more `-O2` + specified options **+ other things** (either *internal* options or adjustments to some limits. Also as the compiler evolve, the documentation might not be exactly up-to-date and could also be a somewhat simplified view of the reality.

Answer (score 7):

You can get `g++` to show you what options is active with the `-Q` option:

```
g++ -c -Q -O3 --help=optimizers
```

The output is something like:

```
  -O<number>
  -Ofast
  -Os
  -falign-functions                     [enabled]
  -falign-jumps                         [enabled]
  -falign-labels                        [enabled]
  -falign-loops                         [enabled]
  -fasynchronous-unwind-tables          [enabled]
  -fbranch-count-reg                    [enabled]
  -fbranch-probabilities                [disabled]
  -fbranch-target-load-optimize         [disabled]
  -fbranch-target-load-optimize2        [disabled]
  -fbtr-bb-exclusive                    [disabled]
  -fcaller-saves                        [enabled]
  -fcombine-stack-adjustments           [enabled]
  -fcommon                              [enabled]
  -fcompare-elim                        [enabled]
  -fconserve-stack                      [disabled]
  -fcprop-registers                     [enabled]
  -fcrossjumping                        [enabled]
  -fcse-follow-jumps                    [enabled]
  -fcx-fortran-rules                    [disabled]
  -fcx-limited-range                    [disabled]
  -fdata-sections                       [disabled]
  -fdce                                 [enabled]
ETC..
```

Comment: Thanks. So it shows one more additional option with O3:  -ftree-loop-distribute-patterns. When I add it to the options set the speed is still 30ms.